# Крашится приложение qt на другом ПК

Tags: c++, qt

Собрал все необходимые DLL в папку проекта с помощью windeployqt.exe.
Версия билда mingw73_32.
Запускал на Windows 7 32bit.
Крашится со следующим описанием:

```
Сигнатура проблемы:
  Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH
  Имя приложения: doList.exe
  Версия приложения: 0.0.0.0
  Отметка времени приложения: 5cc6a169
  Имя модуля с ошибкой: doList.exe
  Версия модуля с ошибкой: 0.0.0.0
  Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 5cc6a169
  Код исключения: c0000094
  Смещение исключения: 00001b99
  Версия ОС: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Код языка: 1049
  Дополнительные сведения 1: 0a9e
  Дополнительные сведения 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Дополнительные сведения 3: 0a9e
  Дополнительные сведения 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: Гугл говорит, что `c0000094` - это деление на ноль. Может проблема в вашем коде?

Comment: Это да, на ноль делить разрешено только Чаку Норрису.

Comment: У меня на компе все работает. Такая проблема возникает, когда я запускаю свое приложение на другом ПК. В своем приложении я вообще не использую деление.

Comment: "У меня на компе все работает, на другом крашится" типичные признаки неопределенного поведения. Я бы проверил на предмет неинициализированных переменных и прочего подобного, 99.9% что Qt тут не при чем.

Comment: windeployqt бывает не все dll собрает. На рабочем компе либы могут быть доступны через переменные окружения, а на другом их нет и либ соотвествующих нет, вот все и падает. Вашеписные либы виндеплой тоже не собирет по-умолчанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже говорилось, идёт деление на ноль.

- Проверьте исключение в журнале Windows.
- Проверьте ваш код статистическим анализатором.
- Распакуйте отладчик на запускаемой машине и проверяйте стек во время падения приложения.